# How to add a "non-mavenized" jar dependency to a grails project

Tags: grails

I'm a grails newby. I am using grails 2.0.3 from the command line (no IDE) on windows 7.

I am just running the 'hello world' example from the grails documentation.

I have a custom jar that is not in maven that I would like to use in my project. I added it to the lib folder and did a refresh-dependencies. I modified the controller to import a class from the jar. When I did 'run-app', the compiler complained that it could not find the class.

I saw several example online where people had to add a line to their BuildConfig.groovy like this: runtime 'httpclient:httpclient:3.0.1' . But since I'm not using maven or ivy, how do I get that jar on my classpath?

The example I am referring to above is http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/External-Jar-in-Grails-td4388010.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Grails 2.0-2.2**

Ok, I finally figured out what I need to do. Suppose my jar is named 'mylib.jar'. I need to rename it to mylib-1.0.jar and move it to the lib directory. Then I need to add the following to BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
    runtime 'mylib:mylib:1.0'
    }
```

I guess that was obvious to everyone but me. Hope this helps someone else.

**Grails 2.3-...**

Just put a jar into the `lib/`. Do not modify `BuildConfig.groovy` (c) kaskelotti

Comment: Having the same issue here, even with your help I can't seem to get this to work [ez-vcar](http://code.google.com/p/ez-vcard/). 

Added the ez-vard JAR to **lib folder**, tried dependency refresh, added to the BuildConfig `compile "ez-vcard:0.7.3"`... still doesn't work, left with the following
`Error WARNING: Specified dependency definition runtime(ez-vcard:0.7.3) is invalid! Skipping..`

Anything you can think of Kyle would be greatly appreciated, very silly issue, driving me bonkers

Comment: Just a wild guess but maybe the dash on the name is causing an issue. Would try renaming the jar without the dash.

Comment: Thanks anyway, didn't work... think there's a deeper problem, going to do a post now

Comment: For me, the setup worked on Grails `2.3.6` by NOT adding the dependency to BuildConfig. Simply dropped the jar to lib/ dir.

Comment: As my experiments showed (on Grails 2.3.11) it's necessary to define dependency at `BuildConfig.groovy`. Otherwise dependency would be included to compiler classpath only. It won't added to runtime classpath (run-app), to WAR and deps report. To be resolved artifact should be named as 'lib/[artifactId]-[version].jar'.

Comment: Following the above steps, I got `Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.osgi:jar:3.10.100.v20150529-1857 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)` instead. And I'm on grails 2.5.6.

Answer (score 0):

if your jar is in lib folder and also entry in buildconfig.groovy and if you can't find jar in your build path then try to use below command.

```
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```