# Appending to .classpath during `grails test-app -unit`

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, grails

I have a unit test that I want to run, but I want to reference a class in another project within the workspace during the tests.  I successfully added the project to the Build Path within Eclipse, but when I Run As - grails test-app -unit I get the error that says `unable to resolve class com.example.domain.Phone` during compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Any jar dependency can be added to a grails project in this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256440/how-to-add-a-non-mavenized-jar-dependency-to-a-grails-project). Alternatively, [this](http://nazcasistemas.com/blogs/pacozarate/2013/04/18/grails-project-common-javagroovy-project-dependency-in-eclipse/) approach would work.