# Where do i add custom JAR files to Grails 3

Tags: grails-3.1

I want to add my jars to the project and use them.

1. What path relative to project should i put them?
2. How do i configure it so they are included in classpath?

Comment: This has been answered in this ticket [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339950/how-to-add-a-non-mavenized-jar-dependency-to-a-grails-project-grails-3-x)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a “non-mavenized” jar dependency to a grails project (Grails 3.x)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339950/how-to-add-a-non-mavenized-jar-dependency-to-a-grails-project-grails-3-x)