# How to Connect to Oracle Database in Grails 3 Project with Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, grails, jdbc, intellij-idea, grails-3.0

**I'm trying to run a Grails 3 app with Intellij IDEA,but I don't know how to connect to oracle database, and where should I put the oracle jdbc driver?
Here is my code in** ***application.yml***
    ---
    hibernate:
        cache:
            queries: false
            use_second_level_cache: true
            use_query_cache: false
            region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    username: "wy"
    password: "19901110"

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/DBW
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/DBW
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/DBW
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED

---
---
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: keepup
    spring:
        transactionManagement:
            proxies: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:

    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
endpoints:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true
```

**and I put the jdbc driver into here:**
[jdbc driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivsU4.png)

Hope someone can solve my problem

**Thank You Very Much!!!**

Comment: Are you not able to get the driver as a normal dependency? I am unfamiliar with Oracle in that regard. If not, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339950/how-to-add-a-non-mavenized-jar-dependency-to-a-grails-project-grails-3-x

Comment: Also, this question really has nothing to do with Intellij, as this problem extends beyond running it in IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

To allow your application to use Oracle as a database, you have to add the **jar** file of **Oracle jdbc driver** into the Lib folder, inside your project directory. 
This can be done by simply copying the driver file into the Lib folder.
After that, simply modify your **Application.yml** file.

Comment: I have already add the  jar file of Oralce driver into my Lib folder (created by myself) 

and add following line to ./build.gradle,  "dependencies" section:
`runtime "com.oracle:ojdbc14:10.2.0.3.0"`

Comment: but it does not seems to work , is there anything details missing?

Answer (score 0):

Put your Oracle jar in [JAVA_HOME]/jre/lib/ext assuming you're using a JDK